# Refactoring nose tests with multiple setups

Tags: python, nose

Assume you are given the following testing code, where the `test1` and `test2` methods run some tests on the `grid` object.

```
N = 10
grid = Grid(N)

def test1():
    ...

def test2():
    ...
```

What is the best way to add tests for when `N = 11` so that the same methods test1 and test2 are run on the new object? Of course one could simply create a new file like below

```
N = 11
grid = Grid(N)

def test1():
    ...

def test2():
    ...
```

but that would result in a lot of code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Using global variables is kind of a sticky way to set up test cases. You should refactor your tests into something like the following.

```
def test1(N):
    grid = Grid(N)
    ...


def test2(N):
    grid = Grid(N)
    ...
```

From there, it looks like you want to take a look at the [test generators](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/writing_tests.html#test-generators) included in `nose`.